# How to cache my static variables in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, class, caching

My regular programs are basicly started from the main() and the first statement is always:

```
Main()
{
    AppSettings.Initialize();

    //etc.
}
```

In a asp.net program, I want to use the same classes but don't have a main() so I use the Global.asax

```
Application_BeginRequest() 
{
    AppSettings.Initialize();

    //etc.
}

Application_Start() 
{
    AppSettings.Initialize();

    //etc.
}
```

This way I can keep on using the global static variables like AppGlobal.ID, etc. I use the same classes and helper classes in WP7 and it's all working fine and I don't care that the initial startup of the 
    application variables in AppGlobal, AppSettings take about 2 seconds to setup.

In asp.net it doesn't work this way because the initialize/setup is repeated with every page request. I would like to cache
    the AppGlobal class and the AppSettings class but how?

**Extra Edit of this topic to explain better the problem**:

Because only with the first page I could use AppGlobal.Name variable in the page code, I added it also to the Application_BeginRequest.

```
public class AppSettings
{
    //

    public static void Initialize()
    {
    }

    static AppSettings()
    {
        AppGlobal.DeveloperMode = Convert.ToBoolean(AppConfigValue("DeveloperMode,False"));
        AppGlobal.DebugLevel = Convert.ToInt32(AppConfigValue("DebugLevel,1"));

        AppGlobal.FilesFolder = AppConfigValue("FilesFolder,Files");
        AppGlobal.LogFilesFolder = AppConfigValue("LogFilesFolder,LogFiles");
        AppGlobal.CompanyName = AppConfigValue("CompanyName");
        AppGlobal.OwnerName = AppConfigValue("OwnerName");
        AppGlobal.ApplicationID = "";
        AppGlobal.Initialize();
    }
}

public class AppGlobal
{
    public static bool DeveloperMode;
    public static int DebugLevel = 0;
    public static string ApplicationName = "";
    private static bool _initialized;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
    }

    AppGlobal()
    {
        //Initialize application (check license, setup folder names, get settings)

        //This takes a few seconds to create
    }

}

public class Log
{
    public static string FileName;
    public static int DebugLevel = 0;
    public static bool Initialized = false;

    static Log()
    {
        FileName = AppGlobal.ApplicationName;
    }

    //etc...
}
```

Comment: Application_Start should occur ONCE (after the application is restarted), not every page request.  I would check to ensure your application isn't timing out/resetting after each request.

Comment: `Application_Start` should work. The Application_Start event is fired only the first time when an application starts , not for every Session_Start and  even less for every Request. Edit: Kyle was faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to make properties of the variable and set and get by session variables although you can cache class by making it serialized

try this:

```
 MyClass obj_cl = new MyClass();

        //Do your Work
        Session["obj_cl"] = obj_cl;   

        //on retreival

        MyClass tempobj = (MyClass)Session["obj_cl"];
```

Comment: but how can the class cache itself? with "cache this"?

Comment: Could you provide an example?